# Convert load balancing function to generator

Tags: python, generator

I'm trying to create a little load balancing function that will intake a list of ordered numbers (these numbers will be string lengths) and output load-balanced chunks. The idea is that we start with a chunk with index 0 (smallest string length) and then add to it the index -1 (longest string length). And we repeat this until we run out of string lengths (stored in `list_ordered`) so that each chunk has a desired `chunk_size`.
Anyway, the function below works fine but is not exactly scalable since we are storing all the data in the list of lists `res`; My question is, taken into account what I want and the code below, could you please help me convert this function into a generator?

Thanks!

```
def chunk_generator_load_balanced(list_ordered,chunk_size):
    n_chunks=ceil(len(list_ordered)/chunk_size)
    res=[]
    direction_chunks={}
    for i in range(n_chunks):
        res.append([])
        direction_chunks[i]=True
    chunk_index=0
    while list_ordered:
        if direction_chunks[chunk_index]:
            chunk_val=list_ordered.pop(0)
            direction_chunks[chunk_index]=False
        else:
            chunk_val=list_ordered.pop(-1)
            direction_chunks[chunk_index]=True
        res[chunk_index].append(chunk_val)
        if chunk_index==n_chunks-1: chunk_index=0
        else: chunk_index+=1
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_keys=[i for i in range(50)]
    a=chunk_generator_load_balanced(list_keys,10)
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't just use yield instead of return in chunk_generator_load_balanced function?

I mean this:

```
def chunk_generator_load_balanced(list_ordered,chunk_size):
n_chunks=ceil(len(list_ordered)/chunk_size)
res=[]
direction_chunks={}
for i in range(n_chunks):
    res.append([])
    direction_chunks[i]=True
chunk_index=0
while list_ordered:
    if direction_chunks[chunk_index]:
        chunk_val=list_ordered.pop(0)
        direction_chunks[chunk_index]=False
    else:
        chunk_val=list_ordered.pop(-1)
        direction_chunks[chunk_index]=True
    res[chunk_index].append(chunk_val)
    if chunk_index==n_chunks-1: chunk_index=0
    else: chunk_index+=1
yield res
```

Comment: The idea would actually be to eliminate the intermediate res, yielding `res` or a chunk of `res` doesnt really change anything since all the intermediate values need to be created beforehand in the while cycle.... My goal would be to somehow convert the while cycle into a generator that would create chunks on the spot without saving them in memory.